# Integral calculation of the product of two infinite sums of a complex function and its complex conjugate

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given the function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$ 
with $z$ complex, I have to get an expression, also approximated, for the integral
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(z)f^*(z)dt$$
where $f^*(z)$ is the complex conjugate of $f(z)$. The final expression is:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z_{*}^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)}dt$$
Integrand is real.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_a^b f(t)f^*(t)\,dt$?

Comment: by the way: ur sum is proportional to an error function. maybe that helps

Comment: function $f(z)$ is complex but $f(z)f^*(z)$ is real, thus integration variable is real.

Comment: I think you miss my point. For real $z$ your function $f$ is real (since it is a sum of real terms). Also, in your integral, you have a $dt$, but there is no $t$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @mickep for your help. I understanded your comment. With $t$ I represent a generic real integration variable. $z$ is not real but complex. Product $f(z)f^*(z)$ is real, because is the product of a complex function and its complex conjugate. Thus $dt$ cannot be $dz$ because, after calculation of product, there isn't any $z$ variable in the final expresision. If we suppose the form $z=x+yi$, product bring us to a formula that depends only on $x$ and $y$: $$g(x,y)=f(z)*f^*(z)$$ and the integral I am searching for becomes: $$\int\int g(x,y)dxdy$$ I search an analytic expresion for $g(x,y)$.